# Mapping FTP folder LAN

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, ftp, cmd.exe

I've old computer with probably Windows CE connected with LAN.
I can view folder and files on old computer, by typing `ftp://10.0.0.3` in explorer (windows 7).
I'd like to backup folder DATA from `ftp://10.0.0.3` to my computer.
I tried some solutions for backup data from ftp, but there should be adres like ftp.mysite.com 
I can only connect by typing `ftp://10.0.0.3`

My folder Data have inside some folders with files, I'd like to copy this folder with full structure.

Can some one know how to solve it ?

Sorry for my bad english.
Regards
Johnny.

Answer (score 0):

There need not be any "host name" like ftp.mysite.com for the FTP server (i.e. your Windows CE device); in reality such host name is converted into IP address like 10.0.0.3 anyway.  Just type the IP address in the host field and it should work.

If you are not able to access by typing `ftp://10.0.0.3` there could be a connection problem between your WinCE and your computer.  Check your connection between the two computers.  Otherwise please make sure the FTP server software at your Windows CE device is up and running.

If you are not sure what software you can use, try [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) which is a free and easy to use FTP software.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I'd like do backup using .bat file...

Comment: Did you try Wget for windows? `wget -r ftp://user:pass@10.0.0.3/data` where `-r` means recursive (i.e. copy all folders and subfolders)

Comment: I will try, I don't use login information, so i should type `wget -r ftp://10.0.0.3/data` ?

Comment: Hi, Wget work not properly, when I try download folder data i got error : 'unsupported listing type trying unix listing parser' but when i try do download single file like `ftp://10.0.0.3/data/data01.csv` it   download properly. What is wrong with folder download ?

Comment: I checked OS is Windows CE net 4.1